# ForEach not working for List

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Having an issue using JSTL and Spring...it's not allowing me to iterate over my list.

Here is my view...

```
<html>
<body>

    // This prints fine
    <h2>${profileList}</h2>


    // this doesn't
    <c:forEach var="x" items="${profileList}" >
        <c:out value="${x}"/>
        <br />
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller...

```
@RequestMapping("/")    
    public ModelAndView  welcomeHandler() throws Exception {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        List profileList = analyticsManager.getProfiles();

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        model.addObject("msg", Integer.toString(profileList.size()));
        model.addObject("profileList", profileList);

    return model;
    }
```

Here is the code building the list...

```
public List<String> getProfiles() throws Exception {
        List profileList = new ArrayList<String>();

        Profiles profiles = analytics.management().profiles().list("~all", "~all").execute();

        for (Profile profile : profiles.getItems()) {
            profileList.add(profile.getId());
        }

        return profileList;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare JSTL before using it.  Add this to the top of the JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```